# How to build libprotobuf.so

Tags: protocol-buffers

I need to **build** the latest protobuf version (24.4).

I downloaded the protobuf-24.4.tar.gz and run `bazel build :protoc :protobuf`

It generated protoc but I can't find anywhere any .so or .a file!

Any idea how to generate libprotobuf.so ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I meant to say `bazel build :protoc :protobuf`. I corrected the error in my question but the question remains the same.